# "Orthogonal complement" of Taylor coefficients?

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, orthogonality

Consider a function that can be represented by its Taylor expansion in $a$

$$ f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{k}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{ k!} (x-a)^k$$

Now for a fixed a, the points where $f(x) = f(a)$ are exactly those points where the sequences $(\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{ k!})_k$  and $((x-a)^k)_k$ are "orthogonal", although they may not be in a Hilbert space.

My questions are:

Is this notion of orthogonality "useful" in the sense that it provides some additional insight on Taylor series?

Can one explicitly derive $$(\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{ k!})_{k}^{T} = \{(b_k) | \sum_{k}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{ k!} b_k = 0 \}?$$

What about for a fixed $(b_n)$ determining $a$ such that  $\sum_{k}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{ k!} b_k = 0$ ?